# While converting the pdf base64 to image bytes the content in the image is getting blur or not readable

Tags: c#, .net

I tried everything but not getting the desired output.

[image]

```
public byte[] ConvertPdfToImg(string soapResponse)
{
     try
     {
         string base64 = "";
         byte[] imageBytes;
         ImageSaveOptions imageOptions;
         byte[] pdfBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(soapResponse);

         ComponentInfo.SetLicense("FREE-LIMITED-KEY");

         using (GemBox.Pdf.PdfDocument pdfDocument = GemBox.Pdf.PdfDocument.Load(new MemoryStream(pdfBytes))) //.Load(new MemoryStream(pdfBytes)))                
         {
             // Create image save options.
             imageOptions = new ImageSaveOptions(ImageSaveFormat.Jpeg)
             {
                 PageNumber = 0, // Select the first PDF page.
                 Width = 700, // Set the image width and keep the aspect ratio.
                 Height = 1000 // set the image height
             };
             //pdfDocument.Save(outputPath, imageOptions);                    

             // Save the image to a MemoryStream.
             using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
             {
                 pdfDocument.Save(ms, imageOptions);
                 imageBytes = ms.ToArray(); // Get the byte array of the image.
                 //base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);

                 //File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\999348\Downloads\base64.txt", base64);
             }

         }
         return imageBytes;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         ex.ToString();
     }
     return null;
}
```